# Import SVG so that each path is on a different layer in Animate CC

Tags: svg, import, adobe-animate

I am trying to import and SVG to the Stage in Adobe Animate CC so that each path/element of the SVG on a separate layer, as described on the [official Adobe help pages](https://helpx.adobe.com/animate/using/import-svg-files.html).  When I select "Import each path to different layer", all paths are always still brought in on a single layer. Has anyone experienced this? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure the paths are separate to begin with?  Is it possible perhaps that the paths in the SVG are in fact compound paths?  Without access to the SVG or knowing how it was constructed, this is difficult to answer. Perhaps consider sharing the SVG on svgshare(dot)com.

Comment: Yes, they are definitely separate path elements! https://www.flaticon.com/free-icon/friendship_1049890

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't import every shape/SVG element to separate layer, then try separating them to different layers **after** importing by **1)** selecting all elements you'd like to separate, **2)** use the Distribute To Layers command. (**Modify > Timeline > Distribute To Layers**).

The only downside is that you will loose any layer names and layer hierarchy you used in the original .ai or SVG file.

Answer (score 0):

Open your "SVG" in Illustrator, and move the assets to different LAYERS first.

Resave as a new AI file (you can try SVG but...)

Import the NEW AI file into Animate CC.

NOTE: SVG's are looked at as ONE FLAT LAYER. (in some programs)

P.S. do the same thing... swear at my computer.. and then try again, lol

Comment: So when I tried this, I got a window asking me which layers I would like to import, which seems like it's closer to what I was looking for, but still, when it's finally imported to the stage, it's all on one layer....